# Mapping XML to single cell in Excel instead of column

Tags: xml, xsd, excel-2016

I have an XML Schema file which I am using as an XML map in Excel. My goal is to generate an XML file from data in the spreadsheet. The map includes [these folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7U9j.png). One of them has the small blue arrow in the icon.

When dragging [the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ49T.png) to a single cell, it maps the tag to the cell and puts a [blue border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs4f0.png) around the cell. This is what I want.

However, when I drag an XML tag from the folder with the blue arrow icon, rather than mapping a single cell, it maps [the whole column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc7R4.png). This is not what I want. How can I change it so it always maps just a single cell?

EDIT: Here is relevant parts of the .xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Generated by Standards Editor (build:R1.6.15) on 2018 Nov 20 09:45:46, ISO 20022 version : 2013-->
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.072.001.01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Document" type="Document"/>
        <xs:complexType name="SettlementInternaliserReportV01">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="RptHdr" type="SettlementInternaliserReportHeader1"/>
                <xs:element name="SttlmIntlr" type="SettlementInternaliser1"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="IssrCSD" type="IssuerCSDReport1"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="SplmtryData" type="SupplementaryData1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="IssuerCSDReport1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Id" type="IssuerCSDIdentification1"/>
                <xs:element name="OvrllTtl" type="InternalisationData1"/>
                <xs:element name="FinInstrm" type="SettlementInternaliserFinancialInstrument1"/>
                <xs:element name="TxTp" type="SettlementInternaliserTransactionType1"/>
                <xs:element name="ClntTp" type="SettlementInternaliserClientType1"/>
                <xs:element name="TtlCshTrf" type="InternalisationData1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="SettlementInternaliser1">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Id" type="SettlementInternaliserIdentification1"/>
                <xs:element name="OvrllTtl" type="InternalisationData1"/>
                <xs:element name="FinInstrm" type="SettlementInternaliserFinancialInstrument1"/>
                <xs:element name="TxTp" type="SettlementInternaliserTransactionType1"/>
                <xs:element name="ClntTp" type="SettlementInternaliserClientType1"/>
                <xs:element name="TtlCshTrf" type="InternalisationData1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Hi there! Could you please include the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Added. Unless I'm blind, I can't see the difference between the IssuerCSD section and the SettlementInternaliser section, even though they are behaving differently when mapping.